# How do I set the working directory for phpunit using the XML file?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm looking through [the documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/configuration.html), but I'm not seeing any option to change the working directory used when running tests.

I'm using PhpUnit as it's included in Laravel. I want to be able to run `vendor/bin/phpunit` from my project's root directory, and have it run using the `/public` directory as the working directory.

I tried running `../vendor/bin/phpunit` from the `/public`, but since the phpunit.xml file isn't in the public directory and I don't want to specify my config file path every time, that won't work.

Is there something I can add to my `phpunit.xml` file to tell it to run tests using the `/public` directory as the "cwd" (current working directory)?

Comment: What for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I don't use `/public` as the cwd, my tests aren't valid, since Laravel normally uses the public directory as the current working directory. (relative paths to files break) I'm aware that using Laravel's functions for getting the app root instead of using relative paths could fix the issue... but it seems like to get accurate results, I should be using the same cwd as what's used in production.

Comment: `public` is not Laravel's cwd, it's the server's "DocumentRoot", where the (web) app is served from. You won't have access to any classes/commands from `public`. Maybe rewrite your tests?

Comment: For a web application, the "DocumentRoot" defines the cwd for when the web server serves the page. If I put `dd(getcwd())` at the top of my `web.php` file, my browser reveals that the public directory is the cwd. Running the same web.php file from the phpunit yields different results. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I thought at least one of the goals of phpunit was to reproduce the same conditions as what happens in production. I'm trying to create tests for web pages, not console commands. So the cwd should be `public`, to match what it is when the code runs in production.

Comment: The trick is dont use getcwd, that is an anti pattern :)

Comment: You can test web pages with Laravel out of the box: https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-tests I'm afraid I can't fully understand what you're after (without any example test, results etc.), sorry for not being able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the feedback I received in the comments and the documentation, I determined the following:

1. It's probably not possible to change the `cwd` that phpunit uses by default (well, it's possible in PhpStorm, but not the command line without writing some kind of wrapper script)
2. Code that depends on being run from a specific directory is not a good idea.

What I had was some code in one of my classes like this:

```
$var = file_get_contents("../some_file.json");
```

This works fine -- until you try to add unit tests. The web server runs using the `/public` directory as the `cwd`, while phpunit will run using the root directory.

Rather than trying to force phpunit to always use a particular `cwd` (`/public`), I decided it's probably best to remove relative paths from the code that rely on a consistent `cwd`. So the line above becomes:

```
$var = file_get_contents(base_path("some_file.json"));
```

I didn't want to change production code that was already working just to get some tests in place, but this change seemed insignificant enough. (and it's an improvement anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'd have to do the actual `chdir` in PHP, but you can define a bootstrap script in the XML (`<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">`) and have that change the working directory.

Alternatively, you can put a `setUpBeforeClass` function into your test class that changes the working directory.